# postgres 9.4 claims that array_length returns a set?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

The following query:

```
select case when array_length(regexp_matches('sss', 's')::text[], 1) = 1 then 'x' else 'y' end;
```

Elicits the error:

```
ERROR:  argument of CASE/WHEN must not return a set
LINE 1: select case when array_length(regexp_matches('sss', 's')::te...
                         ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: argument of CASE/WHEN must not return a set
SQL state: 42804
Character: 18
```

I'm wondering what is happening? How can I get a query like this to work?

This query works fine:

```
select case when array_length('{1,2}'::text[], 1) = 1 then 'x' else 'y' end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha ... ok -- silly me. Without the 'g' flag `regexp_matches` returns one row. However its return type is SETOF text[] regardless.